# Как правильно перенести?

Tags: орфография

Можно ли перенести слово так: "матери-алы"? Я думаю, что можно и здесь все по правилам. Но услышала другое мнение, что якобы три буквы на строке оставлять нежелательно (при том, что на этом предложение не заканчивается).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слова в русском языке переносятся по слогам. В вашем слове деление на слоги такое: ма-те-ри-а-лы. Никаких особых случаев для трех букв на одной строке (не согласных, не разрывающих морфему и пр.) в правилах переноса нет, так что ваш вариант переноса возможен.

Answer (score 1):

Полная ерунда. Даже две можно. При переносе нельзя отрывать только одну букву.
Относительно красоты набора - это ещё можно рассматривать, но тогда можно ставить вопрос и о том, чтобы вообще исключить переносы, благо соврменные программы верстки (и даже обычный ворд) это вполне позволяют.

Comment: Фактически в современных газетах переносят как заблагорассудится. В школе - тоже ошибка в переносе слова уже не одно десятилетие исправляется, но на оценку не влияет (т.е. переноси как хочется). Конечно. хорошо. когда перенос слова не затрудняет его восприятия.

Comment: Согласен, но восприятие - дело субъективное, лучше говорить о ненарушении структуры слова. Хотя и это пожелание - не императив.